# inserting information into a colon-delimited file

Tags: bash

similar to `/etc/passwd`, I'd like a 6-field, colon-separeted file to store some textual and numerical informaiton. Primarily using BASH, how can I read/write to this file efficiently, by index (0-5, or 1-6)? I will be writing to the file using `>`, `awk`, `sed`, `tee` and other similar textual manipulation tools.

I'm **assuming** that I can use `read` with `-d\:` to bring the information from a file back into script varaibles ... Any ideas appreciated.

A comment from a helpful reader states:
**"You should provide more concrete examples of what you are trying to do..."**

I have a backup script that records

- starttime
- end time
- backup type (H/C) hot/cold
- backup success (Y/C)
- Error Reason (reason backup failed)
- extra field

Ideally I'd like to have (empty fields still delimited)

```
e.g.
16.20:17.55:H:Y::
```

or

```
e.g.
17.30:18.45:H:N:files not found:
```

After wards, I have a script that imports this information to a database, into the correct locations. It's easier to just use indexes to import these data.

Answer (score 2):

you can just use awk for reason of efficiency instead of Bash (or others with ability to split on fields)

To read:

```
awk -F":" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file
```

You should provide more concrete examples of what you are trying to do...